# Prolog: handling null cases

Tags: null, prolog

How do you handle null cases like this in prolog?

Here's the code:

```
var_name([], []).
var_name([_|[X|_]], X).
```

My desired result,

```
?- var_name([1,[2,x]],X). 
X = [2,x].
```

and

```
?- var_name([3],X). 
X = [].
```

But when I run the code, I have problems achieving the second result.It fails and return false. I can't seem to understand where I went wrong. I provided a predicate that says to return null when var_name is null.

Comment: Prolog doesn' have the NULL concept. You must provide your encoding and code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In Prolog there is not NULL concept. May be by null you mean empty list, that is not the same thing.  You second result returns false because you have not defined a correct assertion when you pass a list with one element, in your case `[3]`. See that `var_name([], []).` returns `[]` when you pass a empty list `[]` and `[3]` is not an empty list. So to handle that case, you need to add this rule

```
var_name([X],[]).
```

So, your rules should looks like this:

```
var_name([], []).
var_name([X],[]).
var_name([_|[X|_]], X).
```

Then will got your desired result

```
?- var_name([3],X). 
X = [].
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out but I went about it differently.